# I want to display output in a single row in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

[image: I have the input table like this]

Above is the input table.
I am trying to bring all the childsku products in a single row with its count and its associated parent sku.But it is not working as expected

```
         select [Parent SKU (PartNo) ],count([Child SKU]),[Child SKU] 
from tbl_name
       group by [Parent SKU (PartNo) ],[Child SKU]
```

Now I want the desired output to be like this:

[image: Desired Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `STUFF` for this;

Test Data;

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #TestData
GO
CREATE TABLE #TestData (ChildSKU varchar(10), ParentSKU varchar(10))
INSERT INTO #TestData (ChildSKU, ParentSKU)
VALUES
('B001L','B001')
,('B001M','B001')
,('B001S','B001')
,('B001XL','B001')
```

Query;

```
SELECT 
a.ParentSKU
,COUNT(ChildSKU) ChildTotal
,STUFF((SELECT ', ' + ChildSKU
           FROM #TestData b 
           WHERE b.ParentSKU = a.ParentSKU 
          FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 2, '') AS ChildSKU
FROM #TestData a
GROUP BY ParentSKU
```

Gives the results as;

```
ParentSKU   ChildTotal  ChildSKU
B001        4           B001L, B001M, B001S, B001XL
```

Comment: thanks a lot ..... it worked

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Please mark one of the supplied answers as accepted to show the issue is resolved :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `STUFF`.

**Query**

```
SELECT t.ParentSKU, COUNT(t.ChildSKU) as Total,
STUFF((
    SELECT ',' + ChildSKU
    FROM tbl_name 
    WHERE ParentSKU = t.ParentSKU
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '') AS ChildSKU
FROM tbl_name t
GROUP BY ParentSKU;
```

### [**Demo**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/502619/display-output-in-a-single-row-in-t-sql)

Comment: its not working... https://postimg.org/image/45plo3gbr/

Comment: @sql_lover : updated the answer.